# Use javascript to Transfer Text

Tags: javascript

I have got 3 tables in html that at a certain time, i want to move  text from 1 table will move to another. Can someone show me a javascript function ( just a few lines long - don't spend too long) that can transfer text from one `td` to another.

Comment: Can you please post your code here or a link to your jsfiddle so that we can see what you have tried so far???

Comment: add some sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring **ONE** `td` value to another:

Well if you assign a `td` an ID (ex. "firstTD", "secondTD"), you could store it's value in a variable (ex. "tdToMove"):

```
var tdToMove = document.getElementById("firstTD").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("secondTD").innerHTML = tdToMove;
```

Note: This will only copy the `innerHTML` of a single `td`, and duplicate it on the other. If you wish to clear the first entry, run:

```
document.getElementById("firstTD").innerHTML = "";
```

to render the first `td` 'blank'.

You will have to experiment to find a way to move ALL values to the other table, this was just a pointer.

Also, If the text is moving from table to table, and the tables remain identical, why not just place the input in both to begin with, OR, simply run a code to duplicate the table when you would like to move the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Node.textContent* property to get and set the text of a Node.

Here is a link about it:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

I have made a fiddle to show you that in action: https://jsfiddle.net/3dep0msg/

In this fiddle i transfer the text of cell1 to cell2 and add it to the text of cell2.

I use textContent and not innerHTML property, because you wanted to transfer ONLY text!

```
function copyTextFromCell(id1,id2){ 

    var cell1= document.getElementById(id1);
    var cell2= document.getElementById(id2);
    cell2.textContent = cell2.textContent+cell1.textContent;

}

copyTextFromCell("cell1","cell2");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this using jquery.

```
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
      <td>1,1</td>
      <td>1,2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2,1</td>
      <td>2,2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="table2">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>


$('#table1 tr').each(function (indexR, element) {
  $(this).find('td').each(function (index, element) {
      var table2Rows = $('#table2 tr');
      var table2Row = table2Rows.eq(indexR);
      var table2Column = table2Row.find('td');
      var table2cell = table2Column.eq(index);
      table2cell.html( $(this).html());
  });
});
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnvprn3c/).